# Spring Cloud Sleuth Parent-Span-Id is null and not propogating

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I am using spring-cloud-sleuth I can see the traceId and spanId in the logs, but parentTraceId is always null, not seeing it in the MDC. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the span has a parent? If you are looking at the first span in the tree, that one should not have a parent.

Comment: I use @NewSpan annotation so I assume that the previous one should be the parent for the new one. But when I check the MDC I see only 2 keys traceId and spanId.

Comment: Even if I  am manually adding parentid header in the first request it is not being added to MDC. It works once I add the header as a whitelisted-mdc-keys. Shouldn’t it work by default?